# I want to use a graph with Tensorboard that was created using the GraphDef and associated routines

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to use Tensorboard with a non tensorflow app. I can see how to make the graph using GraphDef and associated classes but not sure how to write it out so that Tensorboard will read it. This means that I have the graph in a serialized form and it's not the python graph class from tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

For seeing graph in tensorboard, you need weight, tensor name and structure of the graph. 
I dont understand your question totally,  but if you are able to create graph.pb file then , it will be simple to see that thing in tensorboard you have to run this file [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py)

actually here we are creating dummy graph structure using

```
graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
```

and then giving our .pb file to set all these weight and name

```
   graph_def.ParseFromString('pb file directory to read'.read())
   import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

let me know more detail so that i can help you better way.